# Extracting codes with regex (irregular regex keys)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I´m extracting the codes from a string list using coming from the title email. Which looks something like:

```
text_list = ['Industry / Gemany / PN M564839', 'Industry / France / PN: 575-439', 'Telecom / Gemany / P/N 26-59-29', 'Mobile / France / P/N: 88864839']
```

So far what I tried is:

```
def get_p_number(text):
    rx = re.compile(r'[p/n:]\s+((?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){1})',
                    re.I)
    res = []
    m = rx.findall(text)
    if len(m) > 0:
        m = [p_number.replace(' ', '').upper() for p_number in m]
        m = remove_duplicates(m)
        res.append(m)
    else:
        res.append('no P Number found')
    return res
```

My issue is that, I´m not able to extract the code next to the words that goes before `['PN', 'P/N', 'PN:', 'P/N:']`, specially if the code after starts with a letter (i.e 'M') or if it has a slash between it (i.e 26-59-29).

My desired output would be:

```
res = ['M564839','575-439','26-59-29','888489']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern the character class `[p/n:]\s+` will match one of the listed followed by 1+ whitespace chars. In the example data that will match a forward slash or a colon followed by a space.

The next part `(?:\w+(?:\s+|$))` will match 1+ word characters followed by either the end of the string or 1+ whitespace chars without taking a whitespace char in the middle or a hyphen into account.

One option is to match PN with an optional `:` and `/` instead of using a character class `[p/n:]` and have your value in a capturing group:

```
/ P/?N:? ([\w-]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nFaH1/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EVIw52)

For example:

```
import re
text_list = ['Industry / Gemany / PN M564839', 'Industry / France / PN: 575-439', 'Telecom / Gemany / P/N 26-59-29', 'Mobile / France / P/N: 88864839']
regex = r"/ P/?N:? ([\w-]+)"
res = []
for text in text_list: 
    matches = re.search(regex, text)
    if matches:
        res.append(matches.group(1))

print(res)
```

Result

```
['M564839', '575-439', '26-59-29', '88864839']
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple pattern `M?[-\d]+` should work for you. Here's a demo:

```
import re

text_list = ['Industry / Gemany / PN M564839', 'Industry / France / PN: 575-439', 'Telecom / Gemany / P/N 26-59-29', 'Mobile / France / P/N: 88864839']

res = []
for elem in text_list:
    for code in re.findall(r'M?[-\d]+', elem):
        res.append(code)

print(res)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> ['M564839', '575-439', '26-59-29', '88864839']
> ```